# Pandas - grouping by multiple columns and sorting with one of them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My data consists of ridership data for a fictional bike sharing company.

- My data is contained in a dataframe df
- member_type has two values - member or casual
- day_of_week has seven values - each day of the week
- ride_duration is how long a ride lasts for one session

I want to compare the average ride_duration for each member_type depending on day of the week.

`df.groupby(['member_type', 'day_of_week'])['ride_duration'].mean()`

This code gives me what I want except that the day_of_week is in alphabetical order and not chronological.

I tried the code below, but I think that since I'm grouping by two columns the reindex doesn't work as I hoped to.

```
cats = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
df.groupby(['member_casual', 'day_of_week'])['ride_duration'].mean().reindex(cats)
```

Additionally, if I were to sort by both member_type and day_of_week, how would I proceed? In this example I only have two member types, but say if I had 10 and wanted to sort them as well. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `reindex` with `level` parameter:

```
df.groupby(['member_casual', 'day_of_week'])['ride_duration'].mean().reindex(cats, level=1)
```

However, I would suggest changing the column `day_of_week` to `CategoricalType` before doing `groupby` so that you don't have to `reindex` later. Similarly you can convert the `member_type` column to ordered categorical type:

```
df['day_of_week'] = pd.Categorical(df['day_of_week'], cats, ordered=True)
df.groupby(['member_casual', 'day_of_week'])['ride_duration'].mean()
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks for answering my second question as well!